# Проблема с получением данных из AJAX запроса

Tags: ajax, reactjs

После React компиляции страницы появляется ошибки о AJAX запросах которые запрашивают JSON объекты.
Выглядит она вот так:

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://randomuser.me/api/?format=JSON' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy**

После обновления страницы в браузере эти ошибки пропадают и контент загружается нормально. В ошибке явно указывается что присутствуют проблемы с CORS политиками однако у меня стоит плагин CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, который позволяет игнорировать их на странице моего React приложения. Странно что этот ряд ошибок возникает чаще всего после компиляции...

Также React всегда возвращает этот Warning в консоль:

**Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.**

```
class ItemList extends React.Component{

        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            
            var jsonList = [];
            var Filter = [];
            
            jsonList.length = numberOfItems;
            for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
                this.sendRequest(i);
                Filter.push(true);
            }
            
            this.state = { 
                list: jsonList,
                filter: Filter
            };
        }
    
        sendRequest(itemIndex){
            const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", 'https://randomuser.me/api/?format=JSON');
            xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200){
                    var List = this.state.list;
                    List[itemIndex] = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
                    
                    this.setState({list: List});
                }
            }.bind(this)
            xhr.send();
        }
    
    render(){
            for(var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
                if(this.state.list[i] === undefined)
                    return <h1>Sending AJAX requests...</h1>
            
            return(
                <div className="users">
                    <table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h1>Search:</h1></td>
                                <td><input id="firstNameSearch" type="search" onChange={this.nameSearch} /></td>
                                <td />
                                <td />
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                    {this.state.list.map((item, i) => <Item 
                        id={i} 
                        key={i}
                        visible={this.state.filter[i]}
                        lastName={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].name.last)}
                        firstName={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].name.first)}
                        userName={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].login.username)}
                        birthday={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].dob.date)}
                        adress={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].location.state)}
                        city={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].location.city)}
                        zipCode={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].location.postcode)}
                        email={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].email)}
                        gender={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].gender)}
                        phone={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].phone)}
                        cell={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].cell)}
                        registred={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].registered.date)}
                        smallPic={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].picture.medium)}
                        bigPic={JSON.stringify(this.state.list[i].results[0].picture.large)}
                    />)}
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

по поводу **Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application.**

внутри конструктора Вы вызываете `this.sendRequest(i);`, который в свою очередь вызывает `this.setState({list: List});`.

Вы должны знать, что когда компонент первый раз монтируется, то у него есть последовательность циклов действий: **constructor** => **getDerivedStateFromProps** => **render**. как Вы видите, вы пытались вызвать `setState` (в конструкторе), когда еще компонент не смонтирован.